# What's the benefit of capturing an enemy hero?

Tags: armageddon-empires

In Armageddon empires it's possible to capture an enemy hero. What's the benefit of this compared to outright killing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each enemy hero you capture will grant your faction an additional 3 action points every turn.

The only downside of capturing an enemy hero is that he can be freed by his faction, but if you have a secure location to hold him capturing should be your preferred option.